# python, read specific characters of filenames

Tags: python, character, filenames

I want to open a list of filenames and keep as strings specific parts of the filenames.

in a bash file (run.sh) I have the following code

```
shopt -s nullglob

for path in $emiss_data/*; do    
  if [[ -f "$path" ]]; then
    filename=$(basename "$path")
    echo "processing $filename"
  fi
  ....
done
```

with the above code the whole name of filename is read (e.g. poll_test.txt)

I want to read for example as a string the "poll" (first 4 characters) and as a seperate string the filename without the extension (i.e. exceeding the last 3 characters).

Answer (score 2):

Works for python 3 (I think it will work for Py 2 too), tested on windows

```
import os

list_of_filenames = os.listdir("./") #local folder (or just ())
storage_4letters = []
storage_extensionless = []
for i in list_of_filenames:
    print('First 4 letters {}'.format(i[0:4]))
    print('Name without extension {}'.format(i.split('.')[0]))
    storage_4letters.append(i[0:4])
    storage_extensionless.append(i.split('.')[0])
print(storage_4letters)
print(storage_extensionless)
```

However, if filename has 2 dots, it will save only letters till the first dot